# send() function is never called in server C

Tags: c, linux, server, client

I have a server program here that checks the input sent from the client and returns a message back to the client wether the password is right or wrong .

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>
#include "Practical.h"
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>

#define BUFSIZE 200

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) 
{
    int numBytes  = 0;
    int MAXPENDING = 1;
    char recvbuffer[BUFSIZE], sendbuffer[BUFSIZE];
    char inp_user[BUFSIZE];         
    char inp_pass[BUFSIZE];     
    char pass[BUFSIZE] = "pass";    
    char user[BUFSIZE] = "admin";   
    int attemptsLeft = 3;   


    if (argc != 2) 
        DieWithUserMessage("Parameter(s)", "<Server Port>");    

    in_port_t servPort = atoi(argv[1]);
    int servSock; 
    
    if ((servSock = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, IPPROTO_TCP)) < 0)
            DieWithSystemMessage("socket() failed");
     

    struct sockaddr_in servAddr;
    memset(&servAddr, 0, sizeof(servAddr));       
    servAddr.sin_family = AF_INET;                
    servAddr.sin_addr.s_addr = htonl(INADDR_ANY);
    servAddr.sin_port = htons(servPort);
    
    if (bind(servSock, (struct sockaddr*) &servAddr, sizeof(servAddr)) < 0)
            DieWithSystemMessage("bind() failed");
    


    //accept incoming connection requests to the server socket
    //MAXPENDING is the maximum number of connections 
    //that should be queued for this socket
        if (listen(servSock, MAXPENDING) < 0)
                DieWithSystemMessage("listen() failed");


    for (;;)
    { 
                
        
        //declare client address structure
        struct sockaddr_in clntAddr;
        socklen_t clntAddrLen = sizeof(clntAddr);
        
    
        //return new file descriptor referring
        //to the client socket , all read/write operations will be 
        //performed on this socket
        int clntSock = accept(servSock, (struct sockaddr *) &clntAddr, &clntAddrLen);

        //check if the client socket has not been created
        if (clntSock < 0)
            DieWithSystemMessage("accept() failed");

        //retrieve the data sent by the client
        while ((numBytes = recv(clntSock, recvbuffer, (BUFSIZE-1), 0)) > 0) {

            recvbuffer[numBytes] = '\0';    
            fputs(recvbuffer, stdout);      

        //  if(strstr(recvbuffer, "\r\n\r\n") > 0)
        //      break;

        }
        



        //check if data has not been received from the client
        if (numBytes < 0)
            DieWithSystemMessage("recv() failed");
        
        //read username and password into the server's buffers
        sscanf(recvbuffer, "%s %s", inp_user, inp_pass);
        

        //check if the entered username and pasword is correct
        if( (strcmp(user, inp_user) == 0)
            &&
            (strcmp(pass, inp_pass) == 0)
          )
        
        {
            snprintf(sendbuffer, sizeof(sendbuffer), "%s", "PROCEED\r\n");  
        }
        else //the credentials entered were incorrect
        {
            attemptsLeft--;         
    
            //check if user has no attempts left
            if(attemptsLeft == 0) { 
                snprintf(sendbuffer, sizeof(sendbuffer), "%s", "DENIED\r\n" );
            } else {
                snprintf(sendbuffer, sizeof(sendbuffer), "%s", "NONO\r\n");
                     // "You have %d attempt(s) left", attemptsLeft);
            }
        }

        

        printf("The send message contains %s \n\n", sendbuffer); 
        printf("brefore sending\n");
        ssize_t numBytesSent = send(clntSock, sendbuffer, strlen(sendbuffer), 0);
        printf("after sending\n");
        if (numBytesSent < 0)
            DieWithSystemMessage("send() failed");
        
        printf("NOBYTES: %d", numBytes);
        close(clntSock);

        }

}
```

The message contains prints successfully meaning a message is created for the user however the send() function is never called and the client never receives this message. Anyone know why this would happen?

Comment: If you see `before sending` and `after sending`, then it must be calling `send()`.

Comment: I don't . But if i stop the client application from running , those messages will be displayed.

Comment: You see "The send message contains" but not "before sending"?

Comment: The server may be stuck in the loop calling `recv()`. It stays in that loop until it gets an error or EOF.

Comment: If the client doesn't close the connection until it reads from the server, you have a deadlock.

Comment: The client needs to use `shutdown(fd, SHUT_WR);` to half-close the connection.

Comment: Go through your code and change it so that it can still work if a successful recv() returns 1 each time, ie. each call loads only one byte of data into the buffer, and getting, say, '\r\n' takes two calls.

Comment: I had found the problem , i had  commented out this line which was causing the problem //  if(strstr(recvbuffer, "\r\n\r\n") > 0)
        //      break;
you were right @Barmar , it was stuck in loop thanks a lot